# NaN error in JS number to roman numeral script

Tags: javascript, nan

I am working on a script to convert numbers to roman numerals. For some reason when I'm working with a 2 digit number I am getting returned a NaN instead of the result I am expecting. The 2 digit number is split using substring and currently isn't being converted to a number, but I can't get the NaN to stop even if I do convert the strings to numbers using Number() or parseInt(). I have to be doing something wrong. Someone please help. code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9Lkrjhu/

```
function answer(line){
    var roman;
    if(line.length == 1){
        singleDigit(line);
    }else if(line.length == 2){
        var firstDigit = line.substr(0,1);
        var secondDigit = line.substr(1,2);
        roman = twoDigit(firstDigit);
        roman += singleDigit(secondDigit);
    }else if(line.length == 3){

    }else if(line.length == 4){

}

function singleDigit(line){
     if(line == '4'){
        roman = 'IV';
    }else if(line == '9'){
        roman = 'IX';
    }else{
        if (line/5 >= 1){
            roman = 'V';
            var singles = ones(line - 5, 'I');
            roman += singles;
        }else{
            roman = ones(line, 'I');
        }
    }
}

function ones(num, char){
    var romOnes ='';
    for(var i=0; i<num;i++){
            romOnes += char;
    }
    return romOnes;
}

function twoDigit(line){
     if(line == '4'){
        roman = 'XL';
    }else if(line == '9'){
        roman = 'XC';
    }else{
        if (line/5 >= 1){
            roman = 'L';
            var singles = ones(line - 5, 'X');
            roman += singles;
        }else{
            roman = ones(line, 'X');
        }
    }
}

    alert(roman);
}
answer('42');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `return` statements in your functions:

```
function singleDigit(line){
    var roman;
    if(line == '4'){
        roman = 'IV';
    }else if(line == '9'){
        roman = 'IX';
    }else{
        if (line/5 >= 1){
            roman = 'V';
            var singles = ones(line - 5, 'I');
            roman += singles;
        }else{
            roman = ones(line, 'I');
        }
    }
    return roman;
}

function twoDigit(line){
    var roman;
    if(line == '4'){
        roman = 'XL';
    }else if(line == '9'){
        roman = 'XC';
    }else{
        if (line/5 >= 1){
            roman = 'L';
            var singles = ones(line - 5, 'X');
            roman += singles;
        }else{
            roman = ones(line, 'X');
        }
    }
    return roman;
}
```

Comment: That's it. I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your functions singleDigit and twoDigit returns nothing. Add `return roman;` to the end of this functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error, move your alert one curly brace up, See this

http://jsfiddle.net/q9Lkrjhu/2/

```
    alert(roman);  // it should be here
}

    alert(roman);
```